# Git how to take in consideration only new or modified files

Tags: git

Here is my question :
I have 100 files in a folder
I would love git at first to not take them at all in consideration, like, this is my base project.
Then if i modify or add one file, git would see that file has changed or is new and so, this one would be taken in consideration and could be commit.

I ask this because i really don t want to have all the files in my project to be in my git but only the new or modified files from my initial state.

How to do that ?
Thanks :)

Comment: This is not really how git is designed to work so it's going to be work on your side to maintain this. You will have to avoid using `git add .` or similar to add all the files, and add files to git as you make changes to them for the first time.

Comment: so is there an other software which could do that ?

Answer (score 0):

> only the new or modified files from my initial state.

That implies for Git to know about that initial state, which means... the 100 files would be already in the Git repository, as an initial commit, in order to establish said initial state.

In other words, adding and committing those files to an empty repository and making an initial commit remains the easiest way to then detect changes.

Comment: Yes but that s exactly what i want to avoid, so is there an other software then which could make somthing like i want ?

Comment: @VRene Not a source control tool then. Possible a rsync tool, which would detect changes based on a first backup. (ex: rclone: https://rclone.org/, which works for local files too, not just "cloud")